# Insert incremental value to table

Tags: sql-server, csv, t-sql, sql-insert, sql-server-2016

I need to insert a comma-separated string value to the table called `productsort`. My table structure as follows

```
+-------------+-----------+
| fkProductID | SortValue |
+-------------+-----------+
|             |           |
+-------------+-----------+
```

I have a custom split function which I used to separate values from the comma-separated string

```
DECLARE @Var VARCHAR(4000);
SET @Var = '188,189,190,191,192,193,194'

-- Insert statement
INSERT INTO productsort(fkProductID)
    SELECT * FROM dbo.fnSplitStringToIds(@Var,',')
```

Above query works fine and after the insertion table data as follows,

```
+-------------+-----------+
| fkProductID | SortValue |
+-------------+-----------+
| 188         |           |
| 189         |           |
| 190         |           |
| 191         |           |
| 192         |           |
| 193         |           |
| 194         |           |
+-------------+-----------+
```

Now what I need to insert an incremental value into `SortValue` Column as well, I need the following output,

```
+-------------+-----------+
| fkProductID | SortValue |
+-------------+-----------+
| 188         | 1         |
| 189         | 2         |
| 190         | 3         |
| 191         | 4         |
| 192         | 5         |
| 193         | 6         |
| 194         | 7         |
+-------------+-----------+
```

How can I do this?

**Updated :**

Comma-separated string can be like this `193,191,190,189,192,188,194`. In such a case, My expected output should be

```
+-------------+-----------+
| fkProductID | SortValue |
+-------------+-----------+
| 193         | 1         |
+-------------+-----------+
| 191         | 2         |
+-------------+-----------+
| 190         | 3         |
+-------------+-----------+
| 189         | 4         |
+-------------+-----------+
| 192         | 5         |
+-------------+-----------+
| 188         | 6         |
+-------------+-----------+
| 194         | 7         |
+-------------+-----------+
```

Comment: A "better" string splitter would return an `ItemNumber` for each `Item` returned, e.g. [Jeff Moden's](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function). Is the order important? If so, be aware that [`String_Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) says "The output rows might be in any order. The order is _not_ guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string."

Answer (score 1):

You could do an update, using `ROW_NUMBER` with the `fkProductID` column providing the ordering of the sequence.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT fkProductID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY fkProductID) rn
    FROM productsort
)

UPDATE cte
SET SortValue = rn;
```

Comment: Thank you, But problem is,  I can't exactly say string like this `188,189,190`, because that string can be `188,190,180`, Withing that situation if I use query like your code it makes wrong thing sir. because we order it by  `fkProductID`

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2016, which you are using, introduced [table-valued function `string_split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). I would recommend using it instead of your custom parser.

On top of that, you can use `row_number()` in directly your `insert` statement, so you get the result that you want with a single query:

```
declare @var varchar(4000);
set @var =  '188,189,190,191,192,193,194'

insert into productsort(fkProductID, sortValue)
select value, row_number() over(order by value) 
from string_split(@var, ',')
```

Comment: I tried your code, error shows `Invalid object name 'string_split'.` . My database `compatibility_level` is 100. I can't change it, So have any other way to do this

Comment: and one more thing sir, comma-separated string can like this, `193,191,190,189,192,188,194`